# Inplace Datatable modification instead of using "Defaultview.ToTable"

Tags: c#, performance, datatable

I am working on an Algorithm that is very convenient to use datatables for it's implementation.

As part of the Algorithm I keep sorting the datatable by it's first columns using:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName + " ASC";
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(); // This is the Evil line
```

The problem is, that it seems that `dt.DefaultView.ToTable();` is relatively a heavy operation Memory and Time wise (It takes nearly 60 percent of the algorithm's time!), and soon enough this algorithm will have to handle big amounts of data.

[image]

I am aware I can sort it manually, but I would hate to reinvent the wheel...

So, is anyone aware of a way to get the job done without relocating the full tables each and every time, and without reinventing the wheel?

---

**A fuller sample of code:**

```
var dt = new DataTable();
/*Populating dt...*/
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    /*Some more code here that includes modifying first column*/

    dt.DefaultView.Sort = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName + " ASC";
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
}
```

Comment: Another way is LINQ: `dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r[0]).CopyToDataTable()`, but the `CopyToDataTable` needs also to create a new table with the ordered rows. Do you really need a new table everytime?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the comment. Incase there won't be any solutions that address the core issue, I will test your offer to see if it improves performance.